# Is this a non-example of a $\Delta$-complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-complex

> [image]

---

I know this is not a simplicial complex, but is it a $\Delta$-complex? Here is the definition of $\Delta$-complex from Hatcher:

> [image]

---

I don't believe any of the rules are broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a $\Delta$-complex (at least not with the simplices drawn in the picture, with 2 triangles, 7 edges, and 8 vertices).  It violates the second part of condition (i), that every point of $X$ is in the image of exactly one  restriction $\sigma_{\alpha}|\mathring\Delta^n$.  For instance, where the two triangles overlap, you have points that are in the image of the interiors of two different 2-simplices.  Or, consider the dot in the middle of the right edge of the right triangle.  That's a vertex, but it's also in the middle of an edge, so it is in the image of the interior of a 1-simplex and also in the image of the interior of a 0-simplex.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly it can be given the structure of a delta complex, but the one suggested by the picture is not because it violates the first rule.

Comment: I was thinking it broke rule (i) also, but look at the $\Delta$-complex structure on the torus of page $102$ of Hatcher. The line $c$ is part of the boundary of the $2$-simplices $U$ and $L$. So, the points on the interior of the line $c$ are in the image of the interior of two different $1$-simplices. Doesn't this break rule (i) also?

Comment: @Wolfgang: How are those "two different 1-simplices"?  The $\Delta$-complex structure has only three 1-simplices, the ones labelled $a,b,$ and $c$.

Comment: @EricWofsey So, we are allowed to overlap boundaries of $n$-simplices, and then this overlapped boundary is just considered one $(n-1)$-simplex?

Comment: @Wolfgang: It's not that it is "considered" one $(n-1)$-simplex.  We _choose_ to make it one $(n-1)$-simplex, because we get to choose what set of maps we use as our $\Delta$-complex structure.  The $\Delta$-complex structure on the torus is defined using one $0$-simplex (which we map to $v$ in the picture), three $1$-simplices (which we map to $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the picture), and two $2$-simplices (which we map to $U$ and $L$ in the picture).

Comment: @EricWofsey I see. So, we start with the torus first and then construct our maps? What if we start with our maps first and construct the torus from them? What would be the codomain of the maps?

Comment: Yes, we start with the torus first.  Read the definition: "A $\Delta$-complex structure on a space $X$ is...".  So you must already have a topological space $X$, and then you put a $\Delta$-complex structure on it.  You're not allowed to start with the maps first.  (There are ways to take the combinatorial data corresponding to the maps and use them to construct a space you can use, but that's a separate story.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Ahh I see now. Thanks. I love reading textbooks, but I always miss details. Thanks.